# What is the difference between libsqlite3.dylib and libsqlite3.0.dylib?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm getting started with SQLite databases in an app I'm working on.  I've not run into issues yet but one of the early steps from [this tutorial](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/) is linking the SQLite3 framework.  The tutorial calls for libsqlite3.0.dylib but I noticed another one libsqlite3.dylib.  Is the latter just a symlink to the latest v3 library like the convention for package managers on UNIX or is there a difference?

Adam

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> Is the latter just a symlink to the latest v3 library like the convention for package managers on UNIX?

That’s it exactly.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - I wasn't sure and didn't want to assume either way.

Comment: Sorry, this means which one "should" be used in a project?

Comment: Generally speaking, unless you have specific needs that are tied to the exact version of libsqlite3, you should use `libsqlite3.dylib` when linking.

Answer (score 33):

Actually `libsqlite3.dylib` itself is a link it points `libsqlite3.0.dylib`. 
In other words, in the project if you add libsqlite3.dylib and add libsqlite3.0.dylib to actually add the same file, there is no difference, then why you want to add libsqlite3.dylib?

The because libsqlite3.dylib always points to the **latest sqlite3 dynamic library**, that is if there is a new dynamic library (eg: libsqlite3.1.dylib) libsqlite3.dylib will point to this new dynamic (libsqlite3.1.dylib, ) rather than in libsqlite3.0.dylib! So recommend or to add libsqlite3.dylib!

Reference-:  http://www.databaseskill.com/3734528/